# How to sort LinkedList<Employee> of Employee Object on the basis of 'category' property of Employee Class

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections, linked-list

I have LinkedList object which contains Employee class objects.

```
public class Employee{
    private int empid;
    private String name;
    private String category;

    //Constructors

    //Getters and Setters

}
```

Employee Category may be 'SC','NT','OBC', 'OPEN'. 
I want to rearrange this LinkedList in such way that Employee objects with 'SC' category comes first then Objects having category 'NT' second then 'OBC' and then 'OPEN'.

My requirement is : All objects having 'SC' category should come first in LinkedList after that objects having category 'NT' should come in such way for other categories also.

Comment: make it `comparable` and use `Collections.sort()`

Comment: My requirement is : All objects having 'SC' category should come first in LinkedList after that objects having category 'NT' should come in such way for other categories also..

Answer (score 1):

As it looks like a handful of values, you can create an enum for Category. Define the order for sorting there. And use collections sort with appropriate comparator as shown below.

```
public enum Category {
    SC(0),
    NT(1),
    OBC(2),
    OPEN(3);

    private final int rank;

    private Category(int rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    /**
     * @return the rank
     */
    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }
}

Collections.sort(employeeList, new Comparator<Employee>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
     return o1.getCategory().getRank() - o2.getCategory().getRank();
   }
});
```